# jQuery Mobile count files in folder

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, directory

In my application i have a folder with this structure:

```
images/
       city1/
             1.jpg
             2.jpg
             ...
       city2/
             1.jpg
             2.jpg
             3.jpg
             ...
       city3/
             1.jpg
             ...
```

how can i load dynamically files without knowing their number in folder? If I use a `for` cycle i must know the number but i red that in javascript i cannot read file in folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11489764/1771795

Comment: @Omar thanks, but a file `.php` may work on client-side?

Comment: collect them and send them as JSON.

Comment: @Omar i have followed the topic you post but it doesn't work for me. maybe i wrong something. I created `counter.php` file and placed it into my application root. the file contains this code `<?php echo iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator($_GET['path']));?>` and in my `.js` file i call it with `$.get` in this way `var url = data.src; $.get("counter.php", {path: url}, function(result){// some code});` if i print with an alert the result, it returns me the code instead of value..what error am i doing?

Comment: use `console.log` to show retrieved array. `function(i, result)`. also try `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: @Omar however i think that is impossible that a php file work without a server, this is a mobile application client-side only..can be that when i call the $.get() the php code does not run?

Comment: Maybe, you need to find away to communicate this on server-side and client-side.