# PHP/Jquery - Variable that stores the number of files in a folder and then use it as a loop counter

Tags: php, jquery, directory, counter

**Short Version** Need help creating a variable that stores the number of files in a folder and then use it as a loop counter.

**Full Version:** I thought I found my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489738/how-do-i-count-files-in-a-directory-using-jquery), but it isn't working for me. Since I don't have enough reputation, I can't comment on that old thread so here I am.

I created a JQuery function to add images to a portfolio page. It is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      $('.flex-container').append('<aside class="flex-item"><img src="images/portfolio/' + i + '.jpg" alt="blah blah"></aside>');
   }
});
```

As you can see, I started with 9 images. However, I'd like the site to automatically update when additional images are added to the 'images/portfolio' folder. (Images are named in numerical order such as 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc.)

Based on the thread I linked to above, I created a php file named `numberoffiles.php`. That file contains:

```
<?php 
   return iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator('../images/portfolio'));
?>
```

(My root directory contains both the 'images' and 'scripts' folder these files are contained in.)

I edited my js file to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('numberoffiles.php', function(data) {
        var count = data;
    });
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        $('.flex-container').append('<aside class="flex-item"><img src="images/portfolio/' + i + '.jpg" alt="blah blah"></aside>');
    }
});
```

I tried it both with the `$.get` code inside and outside of the `$(document).ready(function)`, but neither worked.

Something tells me I'm missing something very simple here.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. The AJAX data was not received when you iterate with for(). You can use promises or deferred, or simply $.ajax function with GET parameters.

You can try this without change your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('numberoffiles.php', function(data) {
        var count = data;

        for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
             $('.flex-container').append('<aside class="flex-item"><img src="images/portfolio/' + i + '.jpg" alt="blah blah"></aside>');
        }
    });
});
```

Good luck.