# jQuery get json file from directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I want to create json from folder.

For instance if there is a directory named test with structure as this image.
[image]

From here I want to create json file.

```
{
name:test,
children:[{
name:test1,
children:[{
...
}
,{name:test2.html},
{name:test3.txt}]}
```

How can I do this without using nodejs or server side language.
Just using jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you're basically trying to read folder structure entirely through JavaScript? If that is the case, you won't do without NodeJS or a backend API to provide you this information. JavaScript is not able to execute such kind of IO operations on its own. You can fetch specific local files but not obtain directory hierarchy in any "normal" way, which is the thing you're trying to do.

Check out this related thread for more information:
[Javascript read files in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027571/javascript-read-files-in-folder/1027881#1027881)

Comment: Could I know if I can do this using PHP?

Comment: @Guru Yes, you can, ofcourse. Any back-end language should be able to do that. As I am not into PHP, this is what I found: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to access the html files inside folders and create a JSON file to work as 'index'.

You can create an index.html in the root and, with JS, set a loop to that json file.
You create rows with links to child folders.